# Optimize Blender for macbook pro 2011

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, optimization

So I'm really new to blender, barely been 6 months.
I use a Macbook Pro 2011 running a 2.7 GHz Intel Core i7 2620M with with dedicated graphics, with 4gb of RAM(Yes I know.), and 750gb HDD partitioned into 500gb
I recently reinstalled mac OS High Sierra on it due to a software issue
And before then it ran high Sierra
I'm currently running blender version 2.81 (Thought it would fix the problem)

The problem now is that I really can't use up to half of my CPU according to my task manager anyways[image]
At the top it says Blender is using up to a 100 percent (sometimes more) of the CPU but at the bottom it still says that 60% of the computing power is left on idle

I basically can't use the 3d viewport without it chugging
And I can't even go into rendered view without blender not responding for up to 5 minutes

Any ideas???

Comment: I'd try a linux, which probably solves the most of your software related issues...

Comment: linux? please expatiate

Comment: close all the apps you have open and use eveee and optimise it to lowest ppossible